# Learn to code a CSV Reader program with Java

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to code a Java CSV reader program (using what I've learned so far, I'm a rookie). However, I don't know what is wrong with my code right now. The datasheet is simple:

```
 my,name,is,Tan
 are,you,okay
 i,am,okay,—
```

The output basically didn't show anything. But when I removed the em dash, It worked.
Below is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("List3.csv"));
    while(read.hasNext()){//if the txt file has next line then continue
        String line = read.nextLine();
        String[] lineArray = line.split(",");
        //
        for(int i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++){
                System.out.print(lineArray[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Wait.  What's the error?

Comment: and what is the issue?

Comment: em-dash can be in a CSV... It's just a String.

Comment: Could be a character set issue. But without the error, it’s impossible to tell

Comment: **Em Dash** is a Unicode character (\u{2014}). Use: `Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("List3.csv"), "UTF-8");` to read the file.

Comment: The output basically didn't show anything. But when I remove the em dash, It works.

Comment: I try to use DevilsHnd's code and it works, but why can you explain it for me, thank you. Oh and it also replaced the em dash with some kind of square symbol.

Answer (score 0):

@Tan, below perfectly works for me. Make sure your csv is not corrupted and in the right location and also mention the full path like i did below.

```
package com.java;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\abcdef\\Desktop\\list.csv"));

    while (read.hasNext()) {// if the txt file has next line then continue

        String line = read.nextLine();

        String[] lineArray = line.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(lineArray[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    read.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: This is not the issue. The OP **did** state that the code does work if the **Em Dash** `—` is removed so locating the file is not a problem. It is the **Em Dash** Unicode character causing the problem when reading with the current Scanner object construct.

Comment: Thank you, Kumar. I think DevilsHnd is right since his code fixes my bug.